Want to use active choice parameter value in Root POM path in Jenkins
I have a job in Jenkins consisting of multiple maven projects and their respective pom.xml file. By giving active choice parameter value in root POM path user can select which project to run. My active choice parameter looks like this

I want to give value selected by user for active choice parameter as the path of Root POM as shown below (currently it is giving error)

I have tried giving active choice parameter value in root POM path, but it is not working.

Urgency is not something relevant in [so]. Only technically relevant information should be in the question.

That does not really make sense... each project should have it's own Jenkins job...
